# Setting a custom filter that will exclude the list item titles from the search criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, filter

This code (that I took it from a Book) will apply a filter to the listview that searches only the body copy, excluding the list item titles from the search criteria

```
<body>
 <div data-role=”page” id=”MY-page”>
 <div data-role=”header”>
 <h1>Sports</h1>
 </div>
 <div data-role=”content”>
    <ul data-role=”listview” data-filter=”true”>
        <li>Football</li>
        <li>Basketball</li>
        <li>Tennis</li>
        <li>Volleyball</li>
    </ul>
<!-- etc. -->

</body>
```

```js
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
    $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.filterCallback = onlyBody;
});

function onlyBody(text, searchValue) {
    var splitText = text.trim().split("\n");
    console.log(" text: "+ splitText[1]);
    return splitText[1].toLowerCase().indexOf( searchValue ) === -1;
};

String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,””);
}
```

I didn't understand this piece of code

```
 return splitText[1].toLowerCase().indexOf( searchValue ) === -1;
```

I know that `indexOf` returns a number representing the position where the specified `searchvalue` occurs for the first time, or `-1` if it never occurs
and the `===` operator return a boolean. Why do we want to return a boolean?

Also, I didn't notice that the default filter in jQuery Mobile has changed after putting this code in a script tag before closing the body tag. How can I make sure that this code is working correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my question : Why do we want to return a boolean?

To set a custom filtering function that will become the new default for all filterable widgets, override the filterCallback option in the filterable widget prototype in a "mobileinit" signal handler:

```
$( document ).one( "mobileinit", function() {
    $.mobile.filterable.prototype.options.filterCallback = function( index, searchValue ) {
        // In this function the keyword "this" refers to the element for which the
        // code must decide whether it is to be filtered or not.
        // A return value of true indicates that the element referred to by the
        // keyword "this" is to be filtered.
        // Returning false indicates that the item is to be displayed.
        //
        // your custom filtering logic goes here
    });
});
```

[source](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/filterable/)

Answer (score 1):

Breaking it down to each step:

```
splitText[1]
```

Returns the *second* element of the `splitText` array (as array indexes are zero-based)

```
.toLowerCase()
```

The value of the array is a string, and this converts that value to be entirely lowercase.

```
.indexOf(searchValue) === -1;
```

`indexOf()` looks for a given value within the string/array it was called on and returns its position within the string as an integer. This integer is the starting index of the match. If no match was found it returns `-1`.

```
return splitText[1].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue) === -1;
```

Putting it all back together, this line of code is returning `true` if the `searchValue` is *not* found within the second item of the `splitText` array.

Unfortunately you haven't shown us enough code to know why this boolean value is returned, or how it's used. For that you would need to check the logic within the listView to see how the `$.mobile.listview.prototype.options.filterCallback` value is used.

Comment: thanks for your reply I edited my Question and I I added the rest of HTML code that I found in the book